# Recursion for nested list generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recursion

I need some help at my recursion function to get it run.

I had a database table with following attributes:

- id
- title
- parent_id

Some example entries would be:

- 1,title1, 0
- 2,title2, 1
- 3,title3, 1
- 4,tilte4, 0
- 5,title5, 3

with these entries I wants to create the following nested list

- title1

  - title2
  - tille3

    - title5
- title4

I write the following functions to generate these but there is a failure in there which overfolows my stack always

```
      def topic_nested_list(topics_list)
       get_nested_list(topics_list, topics_list.first)
      end

      def get_nested_list(topics, parent)

       ul_contents = ""
       ul_contents << "<ul>"
       childs = get_topic_childs(topics,parent.id)

       if childs.blank?
        ul_contents << "<li>" << parent.title << "</li>"
       else
        for child in topics
         ul_contents << get_nested_list(topics, child)
        end
       end
       ul_contents << "</ul>"
      end

      def get_topic_childs(topic_list, id)

       childs = []
       topic_list.each do |topic|
        if topic.parent_id == id
         childs.push(topic)
        end
       end

        return childs
       end
```

Comment: The stack overflow may be occurring precisely because the function _is_ recursive.

Comment: Yes the function is recursive, but because of a failure(which, i didn't see) it overflows my stack

Comment: Do you understand how recursion works? Each level of recursion pops another frame on the stack – if the amount of memory required for the stack exceeds the amount of memory available, you get a stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not too sure everything that your code is doing, but it seems you want something like this

```
def process_topics topics_list
  topics_list.each do |t|  
    # do something
    process_topics children_of_topic(topic_list, t) 
    # or do something
  end 
end

def children_of_topic(topic_list, topic)
  topic_list.select(|t| t.id == topic.parent_id)
end
```

It might be good to simplify your example down to something like this then add stuff in as you go.

Your very first call

```
get_nested_list(topics_list, topics_list.first)
```

Is not making sense. You want to cycle through each topic in your list and get the children of that topic and then recurse on that.